# Woocommerce - Cart page - when cart gets renewed with new quantities, I want to be able to pass total

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Ok - trying to slowly work my way through this - bear with me! Will try to describe what I'm doing here.

Using Woocommerce with theme called Flatsome - but this problem seems to relate to how Woocommerce updates the cart on the cart page.

So I am trying to bend Woocommerce to suit - so when client gets to Cart page - they do not move onto Checkout - instead I am giving them a Button to Request a Quotation - button when click opens a modal with a GravityForm in it.

I've been able to get the product list, quantities, price and SKU passed fine into the form ok using a 3rd party plugin ....
but boy oh boy - can I easily pass through the most recent TOTAL from woocommerce??
Not as easy as I'd hoped!

I had originally written this function into my functions.php

```
// Send the page url to parameter called 'gdcarttotal' for use in gravity forms
add_filter("gform_field_value_gdcarttotal", "populate_gd_carttotal");
function populate_gd_carttotal(){
global $woocommerce;

$totalamount = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total;

return $totalamount;
}
```

And yes that seemed to pass through the Total of the Cart ok.

The problem arises ***if the quantities are updated whilst on that Cart page.***

So if I update the quantity of a product - the totals etc all update fine on the Woocommerce cart page total BUT if I then click the launch Quotation form - the value for the Cart Total remains the value of the original total when user landed on that page. So it takes a full page refresh on the cart page to flush it and update it to the correct value.

Someone mentioned to me, Ajax which is beyond my capabilities.

Really just reaching out - and asking what is best way - or how could I write a function whilst on the cart page that will always give me the most updated TOTAL to pass through into a field on a form.

I've got a couple of screenshots but since my first time on here... I'm not sure if I can post or not. Hopefully this description tells the story.
Basically looking to know - whilst on the Woocommerce Cart page, how to pass the most recent TOTAL calculation to a form or page etc...

Thanks guys!!
Gareth

Answer (score 0):

Your base issue is with the language you're using to solve the problem. You've written PHP, which is server-side (i.e., not real-time).

The WooCommerce cart is AJAX, a hybrid of JavaScript and XML, and it's processed client-side (i.e., in the browser) in real-time. That's how you are able to update the quantity and cart totals without a full page reload, and it's how the website is able to see how many items you have in the cart without reloading the page. Because of this, your solution needs to be client-side using JavaScript, I believe.

I'm not a pro developer, so I don't have the exact code to give you, but hopefully this gets you on the right track. You can also read more about AJAX here: https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_ajax.asp